# Verifying user ownership of a resource in Express API?

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I'm currently learning Express with Sequelize and I don't know how to securely verify user ownership of a resource that is being manipulated.

Database:

- User has many Products
- Each Product belongs to one User(ForeignKey = userId)

For the sake of simplicity here is the router:

```
router.patch('/product/:id', (req, res) => {
  // service layer call
  const productInstance = await ProductService.update(args);

  return res.json(productInstance);
});
```

I thought about three possible solutions:

- Verify ownership in custom middleware
- Verify ownership in service layer
- Verify ownership with custom validation in Sequelize

**Middleware**

Here's an example of what I'm thinking about:

```
var isOwner = async (req, res, next) => {
  const product = await ProductModel.findOne({ where: { id: req.params.id }});
  if (product.userId === req.user.id) {
    next();
  }
  return res.send(401, 'Unauthorized');
};
```

This solution however makes me think my API will be prone to mistakes later on.

**Service Layer**

I'm pretty sure that validation doesn't really belong to business logic, but rather to model layer of the application.

**Sequelize(Model) Layer**

I haven't found any resources on passing arguments to custom validation methods in Sequelize(I'd have to pass request user object somehow). Is it even possible?

**Summary**

I'm lost and don't know which way of verifying users ownership I should choose.